# Bootstrap 4 Navbar keep item from collapsing and center

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am practice making a mobile website with ReactJS and Bootstrap 4 and need to create a Navbar as below.

**Normal**

Normal Menu:

[image: Normal Menu]

**Collapse**

Collapse Menu:

[image]

So far I was able to figure out how to exclude items from the collapse menu by putting them in another `div` in the `NavBar` outside the collapse one, but the output still did not match my desire look. Also, when the NavBar in collapse mode expand, it push my content below it down, which is not what I need. I have a logo above the NavBar so I cannot use `fixed-top`. Here is what I have so far:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<img id="logo-main" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/cyclist-design-bicycle-line-art-vector-design-bike-cyclist-design-vector-id1133978305?b=1&k=6&m=1133978305&s=170667a&w=0&h=XL6qa5ZNvRaT6OP4SS8ZG60O5TwfWZnIczIrHfgIJ7M=" width="100" alt="Logo Thing main logo">
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-lg navbar-template">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse order-3 order-lg-2" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto bg-dark">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Account</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Send</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Transaction History</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-row order-2 order-lg-3">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="navbar-nav flex-row">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-2 name" href="#"><h4>Mr.ABC</h4></a></li>
            <li class="nav-item ml-auto"><img class="nav-link px-2" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/cycling-line-icon-vector-id1030341646?b=1&k=6&m=1030341646&s=170667a&w=0&h=0f5Rn6rhIduqX47fTg168axHZK7MlhbiRBt7s_AsOZc="/></li>
        </ul>

    </div> 
</nav>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Is there anyway to achieve the NavBar that I need? More specifically, exclude some item from the collapse menu, change some item position when the NavBar turn into collapse, and stop it from pushing the content below down?

Comment: First mistake is that img is orphan element, no need to close it. Please accept edit for user to get see how to help you

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I don't have enough reputation to put image into a post so I have to put a link, also the code was written for ReactJS so when change it to HTML for code snippet it does not seem to run. Will try to edit it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to play with media query a little to hide some element and show other.

1. 1st thing I made is to igve your main logo is own container to fix
   it on the top.
2. 2nd was to take the collopase button out from the div you added.
3. 3rd I added to 2 div after main menu to show elements when screen
   under 992px.
4. 4th I added My name to your main menu to and play again with display
   to show it.

You will obviously need to change all `class` to `className` to make it work correctly.

Hope it is coming quite close to the question

```css
.container-logo{
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
#navbarNavDropdown{
  position: absolute;
  top: 116px;
}
ul.navbar-nav{
  padding: 0 15px;
}
@media (min-width: 992px){
  #navbarNavDropdown{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.navbar-nav{
    padding: 0;
  }
  .d-lg-list-item {
      display: list-item!important;
  }
}

.logo-main{
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-logo">
    <img id="logo-main" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/cyclist-design-bicycle-line-art-vector-design-bike-cyclist-design-vector-id1133978305?b=1&k=6&m=1133978305&s=170667a&w=0&h=XL6qa5ZNvRaT6OP4SS8ZG60O5TwfWZnIczIrHfgIJ7M=" width="100" alt="Logo Thing main logo" />
  </div>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-lg navbar-template">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse order-3 order-lg-2" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto bg-dark list-unstyled">
        <li class="nav-item"><a to="/main/menu" class="nav-link">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Account</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Send</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Transaction History</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-divider"></li>
        <li style="display:none;" class="d-lg-list-item nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">My Name</a></li>
        <li style="display:none;" class="d-lg-list-item dropdown-divider"></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="d-lg-none mx-auto"><a class="nav-link" href="#">My Name</a></div>
    <div class="d-lg-none"><img class="logo-main" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/cycling-line-icon-vector-id1030341646?b=1&k=6&m=1030341646&s=170667a&w=0&h=0f5Rn6rhIduqX47fTg168axHZK7MlhbiRBt7s_AsOZc="/></div>
      
      <!--<div class="flex-row order-2 order-lg-3">
          
          <ul class="navbar-nav flex-row list-unstyled">
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-2 name" href="#"><h4>Mr.ABC</h4></a></li>
              
          </ul>

      </div> -->
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc eget lacus vel justo porta ornare cursus finibus ligula. Quisque et neque cursus, finibus dui non, aliquam ex. Donec tincidunt interdum augue a scelerisque. Suspendisse congue semper odio. Vivamus in felis at lorem consectetur cursus. Fusce accumsan dignissim turpis, in ornare quam dictum ut. Aenean vel pretium risus. Ut ut tempus erat. Quisque eros risus, bibendum ac erat quis, semper hendrerit libero.

    Aliquam et placerat augue. Ut sed ex arcu. Duis dapibus faucibus est posuere imperdiet. Sed et faucibus purus. Donec ex ex, facilisis id velit quis, congue eleifend nunc. Etiam sed leo orci. In molestie pharetra lacus, maximus dictum nunc iaculis nec. Aenean nisi ipsum, finibus nec ligula id, ultricies luctus orci. Quisque quis metus non nulla tincidunt tempor fringilla ac elit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed facilisis, ligula id faucibus lacinia, metus tellus sagittis turpis, eget aliquet elit felis non risus. Nunc lacus dui, posuere non nisl a, eleifend facilisis ipsum. Fusce in leo nibh. Duis condimentum blandit lobortis. Fusce maximus risus eget urna sodales luctus.

    Etiam rhoncus ornare dui, vel vehicula leo pellentesque sed. Curabitur in odio enim. Curabitur ut ullamcorper mi. Suspendisse condimentum sapien quis tortor auctor elementum. Donec ac euismod neque. Nunc eget sapien a purus viverra tincidunt. Mauris rhoncus arcu ut diam maximus malesuada. Mauris scelerisque mattis lectus sed venenatis. Ut viverra diam in eros lacinia, sit amet blandit nisl tempus. Aliquam condimentum magna et massa fringilla, nec facilisis odio fringilla. Etiam ultrices, mauris ut elementum sodales, sem justo ultricies orci, vitae fringilla dui magna ut sapien. Phasellus posuere lacus nec leo ornare rutrum.

    Suspendisse neque lectus, fringilla quis dui in, feugiat scelerisque turpis. Aliquam porta turpis nulla, sit amet volutpat ex suscipit ac. Sed nec neque vel nibh porttitor laoreet. Quisque convallis dolor sem, non fermentum justo tincidunt sit amet. Aliquam vitae est elit. Cras eros felis, dignissim eget suscipit vel, facilisis et lorem. Morbi vitae tempus lorem. Aenean et ullamcorper orci. Nullam in finibus urna. Sed interdum vel libero at mattis. Nulla suscipit, massa in pharetra dapibus, massa metus mattis dui, quis efficitur quam est vitae arcu. Sed congue tristique suscipit. Praesent eget nibh volutpat, laoreet mi a, facilisis dui. Donec quis tellus et magna accumsan bibendum. Integer ullamcorper nibh non elit malesuada varius. Proin id laoreet mi.

    Proin pharetra nibh non metus aliquam, tempus elementum felis ultricies. Mauris et enim nibh. Donec sit amet mi eu purus ultricies aliquam eget nec nibh. Cras velit nunc, viverra ut iaculis sit amet, molestie sed turpis. Etiam posuere quis enim ac ultrices. Quisque justo mi, vestibulum at enim at, suscipit pretium arcu. Aliquam vulputate ipsum mattis gravida laoreet. Nullam nulla ante, egestas viverra ligula nec, molestie luctus lorem. Phasellus convallis nulla et dignissim cursus. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Cras bibendum condimentum nunc, ut maximus lectus blandit et. Curabitur elementum tellus risus, non semper odio hendrerit id. Mauris faucibus luctus suscipit. Nullam sed ultrices enim. Aenean facilisis risus id arcu consequat, a fringilla sapien elementum.


  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Sorry it took me so long to reply. I have change style up for it to look like what I need but there are still some problem, namely when the NavBar expand it push the content below down, but I need it to go over not push down. Also, when it expand I need the width of the drop down to decrease, is that possible?

Comment: @user3417256 Here I mae modification. I just added `#navbarNavDropdown{
  position: absolute;
  top: 116px;
}` when it is less width dan 992px. to make it go over. for the width of the drop down menu, just set it in the `ul.nav-bar` as I did with the padding

Comment: Thank you so much, you are a live saver. I struggled with this for 3 days straight and finally able to solve it thank to your help. Only need to figure out the icon position now since with ````#navbarNavDropdown{   position: absolute;   top: 116px; }```` the icon start to float up